# Is it necessary to use a spring initializr for creating spring applications?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have started learning about spring and in every tutorial they start from spring initializr, i was wondering is it necessary to use it or we can create a project without using spring initializr ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is no necessary. You can do everything by your own hands. It just helps you to start quicker so that you focus more on the Spring concepts instead of spending much time on "infrastructure" like configuring dependencies. You run it and it just works. Then you can extend it step by step. This can be especially helpful if you just start learning Spring. Later on you should of course spend some time on other aspects that initializr provides you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to whatever is already mentioned.

No , it is not necessary to create a project with Spring Initializr

> The site provides a curated list of dependencies that you can add to
>   your application based on the selected Spring Boot version. You can
>   also choose the language, build system and JVM version for the
>   project.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/20/what-s-new-with-spring-initializr.

https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/

Using Spring Initializr the right dependencies are preconfigured for the Spring Boot version used. These preconfigured projects reduces the setup time and one can start implementing the code rather than investing time on which dependencies to go with.